# CodeHaus Maven JAXB2 plugin error MojoExecutionException: NoSchemasException

Tags: java-8, jaxb2-maven-plugin

**I am trying to build my project ,in that i got error called [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.4:xjc (One) on project tg-tg-tems-ota-common-service: : MojoExecutionException: NoSchemasException -> [Help 1]**

**we are using java8 ,apache maven 3.6.3 ,jaxb2 plugin 2.4**

**Please find below error**

```
INFO] Building TravelGrid-Tems-Ota-Service 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT                [2/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ tg-tg-tems-ota-common-service ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.4:xjc (One) @ tg-tg-tems-ota-common-service ---
[INFO] Created EpisodePath [D:\Sushma_Project\TG_UPGRADATION\Project\branches\3.0.0-SNAPSHOT\tems\tg-tems-servicelayer\tg-tems-ota-common-service\target\generated-sources\jaxb\emt\hotelSearchRequest\META-INF\JAXB]: true
[INFO] Ignored given or default xjbSources [D:\Sushma_Project\TG_UPGRADATION\Project\branches\3.0.0-SNAPSHOT\tems\tg-tems-servicelayer\tg-tems-ota-common-service\src\main\xjb], since it is not an existent file or directory.
[INFO] Ignored given or default sources [D:\Sushma_Project\TG_UPGRADATION\Project\branches\3.0.0-SNAPSHOT\tems\tg-tems-servicelayer\tg-tems-ota-common-service\src\main\xsd], since it is not an existent file or directory.
[WARNING] No XSD files found. Please check your plugin configuration.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for tg-servicelayer 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] tg-servicelayer .................................... SUCCESS [  0.697 s]
[INFO] TravelGrid-Tems-Ota-Service ........................ FAILURE [  0.909 s]
[INFO] TravelGrid-Subsystems .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.941 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-30T15:50:30+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.4:xjc (One) on project tg-tg-tems-ota-common-service: : MojoExecutionException: NoSchemasException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :tg-tg-tems-ota-common-service

D:\Sushma_Project\TG_UPGRADATION\Project\branches\3.0.0-SNAPSHOT\tems\tg-tems-servicelayer>
```

> I am new to jaxb plugin ,can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Please user "mvn clean install" it will clean the target folder and regenerate everything from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for your response,i have build like that only still i got error

Comment: can you please help me with the plugin section of your pom.xml